# Error "Column does not belong to referenced table" inserting from a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, firebird, user-defined-functions, firebird1.5

Using IBExpert and Firebird 1.5, I'm trying to record the timestamp of a log in a stored procedure with precision of milliseconds. Since the function 'NOW' is only supported in Firebird 2.0, I'm using the function getExactTimestamp() from the library 'fbudf' (it's already declared in the database as a user defined function: http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-udf-getexacttimestamp.html)

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE SP_INS_LOGEXPORTS (
    logtime timestamp,
    slogin varchar(20),
    sfilename varchar(80))
as
BEGIN
   logtime = getexacttimestamp();
   INSERT INTO LOG_EXPORTS (EVENTTIME,LOGIN,FILENAME)
   VALUES (logtime,:SLOGIN,:SFILENAME);
END
```

Using that I get the following:

> ---------- ERROR MESSAGE ----------
>
> Column does not belong to referenced table. Dynamic SQL Error. SQL
>   error code = -206. Column unknown. LOGTIME. At line 9, column 12.

I'm sure all 3 columns are present in the table. I also tried passing the function directly as a parameter of VALUES, but I get the same error. I'm sure there is a stupid mistake somewhere, since I'm just learning SQL, but I appreciate any help.

Comment: You have a typo in the values clause, you should use `:logtime`, not `logtime`.

Comment: Yes, but if I do this I will have to call 3 parameters when I execute the procedure, right? I'm trying to stay away from the hot mess that is the code as much as possible and work around the database instead. Right now the procedure is like `BEGIN
   INSERT INTO LOG_EXPORTS (EVENTTIME,LOGIN,FILENAME)
   VALUES ('NOW', :SLOGIN,:SFILENAME);
END
` So I can execute it passing only 2 parameters as in `EXECUTE PROCEDURE SP_INS_LOGEXPORTS ('logintest','nametest')` . Is there any way I can do the same with the UDF instead of 'NOW'?

Comment: You can call the udf inside the insert statement. And I would not expect that to raise the exact same error. Or you could leave it entirely of, and use a before-insert trigger.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it now and it worked. I don't know why I was getting the same error calling it inside the insert. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help, first time I used this site and am glad that it has a helpful community :)